# Can i make android apps using html5 and javascript?

Tags: android, html

> I need help?
>   Can i make android apps using only html5, javascript and css and from
>   scratch.

Comment: this question is too broad for SO... just google it: 3rd Result was: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-build-an-Android-application-using-HTML5-CSS3-JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Build your web application with responsive view features and add a json manifest file to let the android browser [add it to the home screen](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen) as an app. The next time your users opens your app by clicking on your app icon in the home screen it will work like an app(full screen,no address bar etc.,) . You don't have to even put your app in web store.
But the API's supported are minimal compared to a full fledged native app.
The complete list of supported api's [here](http://mobilehtml5.org/) . You might be surprised to see some api's like the battery api, offline storage so have a look.

Real world example: 
visit aliexpress in your mobile browser and add to home screen.

Comment: Installable web apps  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android?hl=en

Comment: The latest trend is to use Progressive web apps that seems to be the furture

Answer (score 0):

React Native is probably the most popular library for developing Mobile Apps using Javascript. Note that it doesn't exactly use Javascript, but is built on top of the React library.

Alternatively, there's a framework called Electron that uses Javascript,HTML, and CSS to build an application. It is built on top of Node.js. It was primarily made for building Desktop Apps. But you can use their Native Node Modules for building Mobile Applications.

You can find Electron here: https://www.electronjs.org/

The docs for the Native Node module for Electron: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/using-native-node-modules

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can do. please check following:

http://phonegap.com/products/

It will help you.

Comment: the user has clearly mentioned "using only html5, javascript and css"